# Brain teaser: Finding the correct rotation (clockwise/counterclockwise) in an hexagon

Tags: math, geometry

Imagine I have numbers which are aligned in a hexagon.

```
     0
  5     1  
  4     2
     3
```

To go from one point to another, I only can go clockwise/counterclockwise traversing over my neighbours.

I want to find out whether to go clockwise or counterclockwise given the input (currentPosition, targetPosition)

For example, to get from 1 to 3, it would be smarter to clockwise, since it takes 2 steps clockwise (1-2-3) and 4 steps (1-0-5-4-3) counterclockwise.

I do not want to do a big `if/else construct`, there has to be another way.

My obvisously wrong solution so far:

```
if ( ((currentPosition + 3) % 6) == nextStation) {
        //both - that part is correct - 
        return Direction.BOTH

} else if ( ??? ) {
    //CL
    return Direction.CLOCKWISE
} else {
    //CCL
    return Direction.COUNTERCLOCKWISE
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start off by determining the number of steps required to go clockwise (you can choose to count counter-clockwise, but I'll use clockwise here):

```
steps = (6 + end - start) % 6
```

From here it's fairly straight forward:

```
if steps < 3:
    return CLOCKWISE
else if steps > 3:
    return COUNTERCLOCKWISE
else
    return DONT_CARE
```